# excel formula: end date minus todays date plus extention days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need an excel formula to calculate the total days remaining for a cell:
end date minus todays date plus extention days(maybe 30-90 amount is in a cell)
i have tried =days360(todays date,end date + number of extention days in a different cell
but it isnt giving me the correct total

its giving me the wrong amount of days. i have a formula calulating my end date as well,is that causing a problem (=SUM(start date+90+#of exyension days))

Answer (score 2):

IT's a bit easier than that:

```
=end date - todays date + number of extension days
```

Dates in excel are simply numbers (where the whole number is days and the fractional part is the time) so you can perform simple math with them.

If you want to get rid of the time, use:

```
= ROUNDDOWN(end date, 0) - ROUNDDOWN(TODAY(), 0) + number of extension days
```

Comment: more correctly: `= ROUNDDOWN(end date, 0) - Today() + number of extension days`

Comment: its giving me the wrong amount of days. i have a formula calulating my end date as well,is that causing a problem (=SUM(start date+90+#of exyension days))

Comment: Use FORMULAS > Evaluate Formula (under Formula Auditing) and step through to see where the error is being introduced and the numbers are not what you expect.  This will tell you which part of the formula is wrong