# excel formula: end date - todays date plus another variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

i need an excel formula to calculate the total days remaining for a cell: end date minus todays date plus extension days(maybe 30-90 amount is in a cell) i have tried `=days360(today's date,end date + number of extension days)` in a different cell but it isn't giving me the correct total

It's giving me the wrong amount of days. I have a formula calculating my end date as well, is that causing a problem `=SUM(start date+90+#of extension days)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel formula: end date minus todays date plus extention days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115728/excel-formula-end-date-minus-todays-date-plus-extention-days)

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be your usage of the `DAYS360` formula. That uses a 360-day calendar and assumes all months are 30 days. Therefore if you are covering a range where this would have an effect, you will see a difference. For example, with the range `1/1/2013` to `6/1/2013`, subtracting the two dates returns `31+28+31+30+31 = 151`, compared to `DAYS360`, which returns `30*5 = 150`.

Try just doing basic subtraction, which will also work on dates:

```
=<End Date> - TODAY() + <Extension>
```

Comment: i tried that i used an actual cell instead of the todays date formula

Comment: im starting to think its my formula in the end date field thats the problem

Comment: @FaithSprings Did you use the `DAYS360` formula or standard subtraction? Your `SUM` formula is a bit unorthodox (since you are summing everything with `+`, and then running `SUM` on the result, which will just return the result), but it should be fine.

Comment: @FaithSprings Also, can you post two dates that are giving you the incorrect results?

Comment: that formula has to cell reference numbers and 90-everyone gets 90days standard.i edited a simple formula

Comment: 3/21/13+ a 30 day extension is giving me 137 days left from today

Comment: use =DATE(2013,3,21)-TODAY()+30 as Rocket Donkey suggests - that gives 107

Comment: +1 RocketDonkey - too many times I've seen `DAYS360` used for date difference......Note Excel 2013 has new `DAYS` function for day difference (Notwithstanding that subtraction works fine)

Comment: @barryhoudini Ah, very cool! I'm still stuck on Excel 2007, perhaps it is time to upgrade :) Agree on the `DAYS360` part - I wonder how many people stop reading after `Returns the number of days between two dates`.

Comment: @barryhoudini there are several names and different end dates and the end dates change when an extension is added so i dont understand how that would work. the answer before 30 days is added should not and is not 107,it is 78 the total should be 108 after the extension.thats the problem

Comment: @FaithSprings Can you show us some of your sample data? The exact formulas you are using plus the data in the related cells?

Comment: i did:  end date  =SUM(start date+90+#of extension days)   days remaining=days360(today's date,end date + number of extension days)

Comment: the formula u suggested works,its just a huge spread sheet and to enter the end date in everyone is a bit much

Comment: @FaithSprings Are you doing this formula for each row of the sheet? If so, can you paste an example row? If not, is the result of `end_date` what you are expecting?

Comment: end date will be 90 days after the start date,unless there is a value in the extention cell,if there is a value in the extension cell then it will be the start date + 90dys + the extention

Comment: start date 12/1/2012, end date 3/3/2013 days remaining 59. but then their is and extension columm and if 30 days is added to that column the days remaining will change to 89 and the end date will chnage as well to4/2/2013

Comment: each row is or a different person and each row will have these formulas for each specific case

Comment: @FaithSprings There are 92 days between 12/1/2012 and 3/3/2013, which totals 122 when you add the 30. Is that what you are seeing now?

Comment: no i have a different cell with the todays date formula, so the formula i am using it the end date- todays date+a cell reference for however many extension days that person gets

Comment: there is also a formula in the end date cell to calculate the end date.tht formula is start date plus 90 days plus the cell refence for the extension cell

Comment: thank you guys for aaallll you help,it really did help me come up with a solution!

Comment: @FaithSprings Good to hear :) If this solution didn't solve your problem, you can post your own answer and then select the check mark under the score - that will mark it as 'accepted' and close the loop. Good luck with everything.